# Callback for Youtube Subscription Button

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there a way to get a callback if a user subscribes to a youtube channel via a subscription_center ( http://www.youtube.com/t/creators_downloads ) button?  Doing an onclick on the link does not guarantee a user subscribed.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there's no API around that button at this time.

Answer (score 0):

turns out they have added a callback now.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button#Handling_Events